# Storybook fetch http addons knobs

Tags: javascript, react-native, http, fetch, storybook

The result I would like to obtain in the first image, an input field where a url is put from which the data must be taken.

In the second image you see the problem I am getting when I try to get the data from `http`.

The module works if I don't use it within the `storybook`.

So I don't understand where the problem is.

Can anyone help me out?

[image]

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react-native';
import { withKnobs, object, text } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

import { Chip, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import Datatable from './DatatableFetch';

const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    selector: 'name',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Trips',
    selector: 'trips',
    sortable: true,
    cell: ({ trips }) => <Chip mode="outlined">{trips}</Chip>,
    right: true,
  },
];

const App = ({url}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data3: [],
    page: 1,
    perPage: 5,
    totalRows: 1,
  });
  const { data3, page, totalRows, perPage } = state;

  const child = (obj, str) => {
    const props = str.split('.');
    let child = obj;
    props.forEach((prop) => (child = child[prop]));
    return child;
  };

  const load = (sort, sortField = '', sortAsc = false) =>
    fetch(
      url +
        (page - 1) +
        '&size=' +
        perPage
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ data, totalPassengers }) => {
        var copyData = Object.assign([], data);
        var result = sort
          ? copyData
          : copyData.sort((a, b) => {
              let [x, z] = sortAsc ? [a, b] : [b, a];
              return child(x, sortField) > child(z, sortField) ? 1 : -1;
            });

        setState((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          data3: result,
          totalRows: totalPassengers,
        }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  useEffect(() => {
    load(false);
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <Datatable
      columns={object('columns', columns, 'Columns')}
      data={object('data', data3, 'Data')}
      //data={data3}
      striped
      stripedColors={['#2196f3', '#ccc']}
      viewLoader
      defaultSortField={'name'}
      defaultSortAsc={true}
      paginationServer
      paginationTotalRows={totalRows}
      onChangePage={(_inPage) =>
        setState((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          page: _inPage,
        }))
      }
      onSort={(selector, sortDirection) =>
        load(true, selector, sortDirection === 'asc')
      }
      paginationComponentOptions={(currentPage, totalPage) =>
        `${currentPage} di ${totalPage}`
      }
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#ccc",
        borderRadius: 4,
      }}
    />
  );
};

storiesOf('DatatableFetch', module)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .add('example', () => {
    return <App url={text("Url", "https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger?page=", "Url")} />;
  });
```

DatatableFetch.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { DataTable, ProgressBar, Colors, Text } from 'react-native-paper';

function Datatable({
  columns,
  data = [],
  noTableHead = false,
  striped = false,
  stripedColors = ['#2196f3','#8bc34a'],
  viewLoader = false,
  defaultSortField,
  defaultSortAsc,
  page: _page = 1,
  perPage: _perPage = 5,
  pagination = false,
  paginationComponentOptions,
  noDataComponent = <Text>There are no records to display.</Text>,
  style,
  paginationServer = false,
  paginationTotalRows = 0,
  onChangePage,
  onSort
}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    datatable: data,
    page: _page - 1,
    perPage: _perPage,
    numberOfPages: Math.ceil( (paginationServer ? paginationTotalRows : data.length) / _perPage),
    sortField: defaultSortField,
    sortAsc: defaultSortAsc,
    progressBar: false,
    loading: false,
  });

  const {
    datatable,
    page,
    perPage,
    numberOfPages,
    sortField,
    sortAsc,
    progressBar,
    loading,
  } = state;

  /*useEffect(() => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      datatable: data,
      numberOfPages: Math.ceil( (paginationServer ? paginationTotalRows : data.length) / _perPage)
    }));
  }, [data]);*/

  const dataPagination = !paginationServer && pagination
    ? datatable.slice(perPage * page, perPage * (page + 1))
    : datatable;

  const getValue = (object, { selector, cell }) => {
    if (cell) return cell(object);
    return selector
      .replace(/\[/g, '.')
      .replace(/\]/g, '')
      .split('.')
      .reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('a')
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      progressBar: true,
    }));
    sort(sortField, sortAsc);
  }, [data]);

  const child = (obj, str) => {
    const props = str.split('.');
    let child = obj;
    props.forEach((prop) => (child = child[prop]));
    return child;
  };

  const sort = async (sortField, sortAsc) => {
    var copyData = Object.assign([], data);
    var result = paginationServer ? copyData : copyData.sort((a, b) => {
      let [x, z] = sortAsc ? [a, b] : [b, a];
      return child(x, sortField) > child(z, sortField) ? 1 : -1;
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      setState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        datatable: result,
        numberOfPages: Math.ceil( (paginationServer ? paginationTotalRows : result.length) / _perPage),
        progressBar: false,
        loading: true,
      }));
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <DataTable style={style}>
      {!noTableHead && (
        <DataTable.Header>
          {columns.map((item, i) => {
            const sortDirection =
              datatable.length > 0 &&
              !progressBar &&
              sortField === item.selector
                ? !sortAsc
                  ? 'ascending'
                  : 'descending'
                : null;

            return (
              !item.omit && (
                <DataTable.Title
                  key={i}
                  onPress={() => {
                    if (item.sortable) {
                      const sortAscC =
                        sortField === item.selector ? !sortAsc : true;
                      setState((prev) => ({
                        ...prev,
                        sortField: item.selector,
                        sortAsc: sortAscC,
                        progressBar: true,
                      }));
                      if(paginationServer) onSort(item.selector, sortAscC ? 'asc' : 'desc')
                      else sort(item.selector, sortAscC);
                    }
                  }}
                  sortDirection={sortDirection}
                  numeric={item.right}
                  style={item.styleHeader}>
                  {item.name} {false && sortDirection}
                </DataTable.Title>
              )
            );
          })}
        </DataTable.Header>
      )}

      {viewLoader && progressBar && (
        <ProgressBar indeterminate color={Colors.blue900} />
      )}

      {!progressBar && datatable.length === 0 && (
        <View
          style={{
            margin: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          {noDataComponent}
        </View>
      )}

      {loading &&
        dataPagination.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <DataTable.Row
              key={i}
              style={{
                opacity: progressBar ? 0.2 : 1,
                backgroundColor: striped
                  ? i % 2
                    ? stripedColors[0]
                    : stripedColors[1]
                  : null,
              }}>
              {columns.map((headerItem, j) => {
                return (
                  !headerItem.omit && (
                    <DataTable.Cell
                      key={j}
                      numeric={headerItem.right}
                      style={headerItem.styleRow}>
                      {getValue(item, headerItem)}
                    </DataTable.Cell>
                  )
                );
              })}
            </DataTable.Row>
          );
        })}

      {(pagination || paginationServer) && (
        <DataTable.Pagination
          page={page}
          numberOfPages={numberOfPages}
          onPageChange={(page) => {
            onChangePage && onChangePage(page+1)
            if(true){
              setState((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                progressBar: true,
              }));
              setTimeout(() => {
                setState((prev) => ({
                  ...prev,
                  page: page,
                  progressBar: false,
                }));
              }, 2000);
            }
          }}
          label={paginationComponentOptions ? paginationComponentOptions(page + 1, numberOfPages) : `${page + 1}-${numberOfPages} of ${datatable.length}`}
        />
      )}
    </DataTable>
  );
}

export default Datatable;
```